# My laptop see only 3GB RAM

Tags: memory, memtest

I have the **Toshiba Satellite A100-011** and i upgrade the RAM from 2GB to 4GB but when i boot to windows i have usable only 3GB RAM and on Ubuntu have 2.9Gib RAM. The BIOS see 3143680KB of RAM.

**I try these fixes:**

- I run memtest86+ and and is not find any problem. But below of the test information is display and the 2 RAM modules with the correct size of each module.
- I switch the position of RAM modules, and again is not see 4GB on any OS.

Comment: Update bios to newest. Does your ram speed is not faster than in specification?

Comment: there is not any new version for my BIOS

Comment: What is your Operating System: 32 or 64bit?

Comment: @lluke 64bit (windows and linux)

Comment: Shared video ram in bios?